# Which combination of overloads is most performant?

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11

I have a function like this:

```
void init_str(std::string _s)
{
    std::string s{_s};
}
```

And I want to have an optimization by allowing a `const char*` overload to avoid creating a temporary `std::string`.

```
void init_str(const char* c)
{
    std::string s{c};
}
```

But I can also use forwarding as well.

```
template<typename T>
void init_str(T&& t)
{
    std::string s{std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

But the preference of overloads by the compiler is:

- `const char*`
- forwarding
- `std::string`

So what combination of overloads should I prefer?

Comment: There shouldn't be significant differences. If you're in doubt about such things, measure.

Comment: That function will just be completely optimised out anyway. The real answer will depend on the real function.

Comment: I'd follow what @πάνταῥεῖ said. `std::string_view` (TS) could also be a good solution (overkill?)

Comment: Your first example accepts the string by copy, then you make another copy suggesting you need two copies. But your `const char*` example only leaves you with one string. If you really only need one string then your first example doesn't need to copy the parameter to a second string. Also its constructor should make the best choice depending on what gets passed in as it has move semantics. You probably can't get better than that if you only want one string. Just accept the parameter by copy and don't re-copy it.

Comment: `T&& t` will create a separate function template specialization depending on the length of raw string literals passed as its argument unless you have `const char* c` overload

Answer (score 7):

Assuming c++11 or better, the most performant solution is the one you have not yet tried:

```
void init_str(std::string s)
{
  // just use s
}
```

Because copy elision will ensure that no un-necessary temporary is constructed at all.

this constructs s using the std::string(const char*) constructor (1 construction total):

```
init_str("xxx");
```

this constructs s with a copy constructor:

```
std::string x; // 1 constructor
init_str(x);   // 1 copy constructor
```

this constructs s with a move constructor

```
std::string x;            // 1 constuctor
init_str(std::move(x));   // 1 move constructor
```

this does not actually create the temporary at all:

```
std::string get_str() {
    std::string s("xxx");   // 1 constructor, but...
    return s;               // ...because of RVO it's constructed at the call site
}

init_str(get_str());        // ... which is actually the constructor of s in init_str's arg list
// ... total constructors: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider your input parameter:

```
void init_str(std::string s)
{
    // use s here ...
}
```

Whatever you call the function will the `std::string` constructors should do the most efficient thing.

If you call with a temporary, it will be *moved* (`std::move()`) in. If you call it with a `const char*` it will be efficiently copied in via the overloaded `std::string()` constructor.

So you can't really improve on the efficiency of how your parameter string is created.

Your question is unclear if you want two strings or just one. If you need two strings in your function then:

```
void init_str(std::string s1)
{
    std::string s2 = s1;

    // use s1 & s2 here ...
}
```

Given that you want a *copy* of your parameter string then *moving* is not an option. You can't get better than simply making the second string equal to the first. The `std::string` assignment operator has all the info it needs to make the most efficient copy.

I don't see how any of your other solutions can improve on this.